# Prove cosh(x) and sinh(x) are continuous.

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, hyperbolic-functions

I failed this task at my univiersity and i do not understand why. No feedback was given. I have to prove that cosh(x) and sinh(x) are continious. I proved it for cosh(x) and said the same principles could be applied to sinh(x). Here is my argument:

$cosh(x) = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$

$e^x$ is continuous.

$e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^x}$u and even though 1 is being divided by $e^x$ it is still continuous since having it divided by one does not change continuity.

When you add 2 continuous functions you get another continuous function, so:

$e^x + e^{-x}$ is still continuous.

Diving by 2 does not change continuity. $\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$ is therefore continuous. The same principle can be applied to sinh(x).

Is there something wrong with my argumentation or am I not explicit enough? What am I doing wrong?

By the way, differential calculus is not allowed in the task.

Comment: $y = x$ is continuous, but $y = \frac 1x$ is not.

Comment: @Deepak $f(x) = \frac 1x$ is continuous on its domain.

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is the composition of $x \mapsto e^x$ and $x \mapsto -x$. It is easier if you consider it this way.

Comment: @Deepak It's not? Then how are the functions continious?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 $y = x$ is continuous over the domain of all real numbers (including zero), but the same domain does not apply for the continuity of the reciprocal. That was my point.

Comment: @VictorVH: The gist of your reasoning is fine, aside from the possible snag about dividing by $e^{x}$ as explained in T. Eskin's answer. It's also possible whoever graded you work took exception to phrases such as "$e^{x}$ is continuous". Technically, it's the _exponential function_, $\exp$ or $x \mapsto e^{x}$, that's continuous. Do you have a TA or instructor you can ask?

Answer (score 5):

Your reasoning looks good, except when it comes to $e^{-x}$. True, that dividing $1$ by $e^{x}$ is still continuous, but why? The reason is that $e^{x}\neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and hence $e^{-x}=\frac{1}{e^{x}}$ is continuous as well since $e^{x}$ is.

Comment: @VictorVH: you're welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with your reasoning. If we had a function $g(x) = \frac 12(f(x) + f(x)^{-1})$ where $f$ is continuous and *does* vanish somewhere, when exactly would $g$ not be continuous?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I don't see how that is relevant here. In our case $f$ never vanishes. And that being the case, $f(x)^{-1}$ is the composition of $x\mapsto f(x)$ and $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, which are both continuous in the given sets as the range of $x\mapsto f(x)$ does not contain $0$: the only discontinuity point of the latter function.