# Show $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$ are continious using $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, hyperbolic-functions

I have to prove that $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$ are continuous functions. I *have* to use the hyperbolic addition formula, and the inequalities: 
$|\sinh x| \leq 3|x|, \, |x|<\frac{1}{2}$ 
$|\cosh x -1| \leq 3|x|, \, |x|<\frac{1}{2}$ 
I've tried doing an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof, but I am only able to show it for $|x|<1/2$ or not at all. I believe it's beneficial to first look at $x\in[0,\infty )$ and then use symmetry to extend the argument to all of $R$. Here's what I've tried: 
$\cosh x \,\mathrm{is\, continious \,on} \, R_+ \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in R_+ \forall \epsilon >0\exists\delta>0: |\cosh x-\cosh y|<\varepsilon\, \mathrm{ such\, that}\, |x-y|<\delta$
$|\cosh x - \cosh y| = |\cosh x -1 + 1 - \cosh y| = |(\cosh x -1) - (\cosh y -1)|$ 
$\leq |3|x|-3|y|| = 3||x|-|y||\leq3|x-y|$
And since $|x-y|<\delta$, one can pick a $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. The problem is, this is only valid for $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ (and thus not on the desired the interval) because of the inequality I used. Also, I haven't used the hyperbolic addition formula.

This thread: [Prove cosh(x) and sinh(x) are continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687815/prove-coshx-and-sinhx-are-continuous) deals with the same problem, but my problem must not be solved simply by stating that $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$ consists of continious functions, as that thread does.

Comment: Hint: $$\left\lvert e^x-e^{x_0}\right\rvert=e^{x_0}\cdot \lvert e^{x-x_0}-1\rvert\le e^{x_0}\cdot 2\lvert(x-x_0)\rvert$$

Comment: @vitamind I'm sorry, I don't quite get that last step. I assume you're using exp(x)>=1+x. But I get:
 exp(x0)⋅|exp(x−x0)−1|>= exp(x0) ⋅ |x - x0|
So where does your factor 2 come from? And how did you get the inequality to turn the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *have to*, the addition formula $\cosh(x+h)=\cosh(x)\cosh(h)+\sinh(x)\sinh(h)$ and $\sinh(x+h)=\cosh(x)\sinh(h)+\sinh(x)\cosh(h)$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cosh(x+h)-\cosh(x)&=\cosh(x)[\cosh(h)-1]+\sinh(x)\sinh(h)\\
\sinh(x+h)-\sinh(x)&=\sinh(x)[\cosh(h)-1]+\cosh(x)\sinh(h).
\end{aligned}
$$
So by triangle inequality, the given bound, and $\cosh(x)+\sinh(x)=e^x$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lvert\cosh(x+h)-\cosh(x)\rvert&\leq\cosh(x)\overbrace{[\cosh(h)-1]}^{\leq 3\lvert h\rvert}+\lvert\sinh(x)\overbrace{\sinh(h)}^{\leq 3\lvert h\rvert}\rvert\leq 3 e^x\lvert h\rvert
\\
\lvert\sinh(x+h)-\sinh(x)\rvert&=\lvert\sinh(x)\rvert\underbrace{[\cosh(h)-1]}_{\leq 3\lvert h\rvert}+\cosh(x)\underbrace{\lvert\sinh(h)\rvert}_{\leq 3\lvert h\rvert}\leq 3e^x\lvert h\rvert\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence if we choose $\delta<\min(\frac13\epsilon e^{-x},\frac12)$, we get $\lvert h\rvert<\delta\implies \lvert f(x+h)-f(x)\rvert\leq\epsilon$ for both $f=\cosh$ and $f=\sinh$.

Comment: Since |sinhx|<3|x| and |coshx -1|<3|x| is not valid for all real numbers, does your answer show that cosh and sinh is continious on all real numbers?

Comment: I'm only using it for $h$ not the arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\lvert h\rvert<\frac12$ is built in so $\lvert\sinh h\rvert\leq3\lvert h\rvert$ and $\cosh(h)-1\leq3\lvert h\rvert$ are valid.